# remove drawing from surface view

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

I draw a circle in a surfaceview each time you touch the screen using this code.

```
     Surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
     surfaceHolder = Surface.getHolder();
     paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
     paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);


     Surface.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             switch (event.getAction()) {
                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                     int mX = (int) (event.getX());
                     int mY = (int) (event.getY());

                      if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                       canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                         circlePoints.add(new Point(mX, mY);
                         for (Point p : circlePoints) {
                             canvas.drawCircle(p.x, p.y, 40, paint);

                         }
                         surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                     }
                     break;
             }

             return true;
         }
     });
```

Now i want to clear my surface view when i click the button clear using this code:

```
    Button Clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
    Clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                //canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
            circlePoints.clear(); 
         }
      });
```

all existing circles on the surface view disappear, but  when I touch the screen again to draw others circles the old circles appear.
I can not find any explanation why they appear again . 
Thank you to giving me another solution to clear my Surfaceview probly.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply, color the whole `Canvas`. For example assuming your initial `Canvas` color was `White` you could do this:

```
 canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
```

The `Color` is taken from this class `android.graphics.Color`

**EDIT:**

It seems that your `onClick` code works fine, but it removes only one circle at a time, since on `ACTION_DOWN` we are drawing the circles on a new canvas each time. Similarly to remove all the circles we have to over draw on the canvas the same amount of times as the count of the circles.

Hence, you should change your `onClick` like this:

```
    Clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                for(Point p : circlePoints) {
                    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
                circlePoints.clear();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i try this method but the problem persists

Comment: Can you post the code you tried? As i strongly believe this should work.

Comment: the codes are up. the problem is that all existing circles on the surface view disappear, but when I touch the screen again to draw others circles the old circles appear.

Comment: Your code looks okay. I don't understand why it isn't working. I will try and resolve your problem on the weekend.